# new jooq/gradle configuration not generating any jooq classes

Tags: gradle, h2, jooq

I've gotten a Ratpack application working using gradle (v2.1.0) and jooq (v3.8.1) for generating class files.

Here's my *build.gradle* file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.ratpack:ratpack-gradle:1.5.4"
    classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3"
    classpath "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34"
    classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.8.1'
    classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.186'
  }
}

plugins {
    id "com.github.michaelruocco.embedded-mysql-plugin" version "2.1.7"
}

apply plugin: "io.ratpack.ratpack-java"
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
apply plugin: "idea"

// db dump: mysqldump -P 3306 -h 127.0.0.1 -u embedded_user -ppassword --all-databases
def RDS_HOSTNAME = "localhost"
def RDS_PORT = 3306
def RDS_DB_NAME = "test"
def RDS_USERNAME = "embedded_user"
def RDS_PASSWORD = "password"

run {
    environment "RDS_HOSTNAME", RDS_HOSTNAME
    environment "RDS_PORT", RDS_PORT
    environment "RDS_DB_NAME", RDS_DB_NAME
    environment "RDS_USERNAME", RDS_USERNAME
    environment "RDS_PASSWORD", RDS_PASSWORD
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

ext {
    ratpackPac4jVersion="2.0.0"
    ratpackVersion="1.5.1"
    pac4jVersion="2.1.0"
}

embeddedMysql {
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + RDS_HOSTNAME + ':' + RDS_PORT + "/" + RDS_DB_NAME
    username = RDS_USERNAME
    password = RDS_PASSWORD
    version = 'v5_7_latest'
}

import org.jooq.util.jaxb.*
import org.jooq.util.*

task jooqCodegen {
  doLast {
    String init = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/init.sql".replaceAll('\\\\', '/') 
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
      .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
      .withDriver("org.h2.Driver") 
      .withUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:todo;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '$init'") 
    )
      .withGenerator(new Generator()
        .withDatabase(new Database()
          .withName("org.jooq.util.h2.H2Database")
          .withIncludes(".*")
          .withExcludes("")
          .withInputSchema("PUBLIC")
        )
      .withTarget(new Target()
        .withDirectory("$projectDir/src/main/auto_generated") 
        .withPackageName("jooq"))) 
    GenerationTool.generate(configuration)
  }
}

run.dependsOn startEmbeddedMysql

dependencies {
    runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"

    compile "org.pac4j:ratpack-pac4j:${ratpackPac4jVersion}"
    compile "io.ratpack:ratpack-groovy:${ratpackVersion}"
    compile "io.ratpack:ratpack-test:${ratpackVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-core:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-openid:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-http:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-gae:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-oidc:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-jwt:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile ratpack.dependency('hikari')
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13"
    compile group: 'io.ratpack', name: 'ratpack-thymeleaf', version: '1.4.0-rc-3'
    compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34"
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.8.1'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.2.Final'

}

mainClassName = "xyz.mealsahead.Main"
```

I started working with the jooq API and realized I'm using an old version of jooq, so want to switch to the newer API.

The first thing I tried was just changing the two jooq references from 3.8.1 to 3.11.2.  This caused problems as it seems the jooq version changed the API such that the jooq config no longer works:

```
> startup failed:
  build file build.gradle': 72: unable to resolve class Target 
   @ line 72, column 19.
           .withTarget(new Target()
                       ^

  build file build.gradle': 66: unable to resolve class Database 
   @ line 66, column 23.
             .withDatabase(new Database()
                           ^

  build file build.gradle': 65: unable to resolve class Generator 
   @ line 65, column 22.
           .withGenerator(new Generator()
                          ^

  etc.
```

jooq has an example for a gradle setup, but I don't understand how it could work: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle/.  The strange thing is *buildscript* block in that example isn't at the top, which from what I see in my terminal and online is not allowed:

```
build.gradle': 24: only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed
```

so I don't know how that example would work unless it's for a different version of gradle than I have (earlier or later).

Looking at the doc for the jooq-gradle plugin (https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin), it has pretty clear steps for setting up the gradle script, so I modified the build.gradle file to look like the following:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.ratpack:ratpack-gradle:1.5.4"
    classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3"
    classpath "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34"
    classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.186'
    classpath 'nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:3.0.1'
  }
}

plugins {
    id "com.github.michaelruocco.embedded-mysql-plugin" version "2.1.7"
}

apply plugin: 'nu.studer.jooq'
apply plugin: "io.ratpack.ratpack-java"
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
apply plugin: "idea"

// db dump: mysqldump -P 3306 -h 127.0.0.1 -u embedded_user -ppassword --all-databases
def RDS_HOSTNAME = "localhost"
def RDS_PORT = 3306
def RDS_DB_NAME = "test"
def RDS_USERNAME = "embedded_user"
def RDS_PASSWORD = "password"

run {
    environment "RDS_HOSTNAME", RDS_HOSTNAME
    environment "RDS_PORT", RDS_PORT
    environment "RDS_DB_NAME", RDS_DB_NAME
    environment "RDS_USERNAME", RDS_USERNAME
    environment "RDS_PASSWORD", RDS_PASSWORD
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

ext {
    ratpackPac4jVersion="2.0.0"
    ratpackVersion="1.5.1"
    pac4jVersion="2.1.0"
}

embeddedMysql {
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + RDS_HOSTNAME + ':' + RDS_PORT + "/" + RDS_DB_NAME
    username = RDS_USERNAME
    password = RDS_PASSWORD
    version = 'v5_7_latest'
}

dependencies {
     jooqRuntime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.193'
}

jooq {
    String init = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/init.sql".replaceAll('\\\\', '/') 

  version = '3.11.2'
  edition = 'OSS'
  sample(sourceSets.main) {
    jdbc {
      driver = "org.h2.Driver" //'org.postgresql.Driver'
      url = "jdbc:h2:mem:todo;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '$init'" //'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample'
                  user = 'sa'
            password = ''
    }
    generator {
      name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
      database {
        name = 'org.jooq.meta.h2.H2Database'
        includes = '.*'
        excludes = ''
        inputSchema = 'public'
      }
      generate {
        relations = true
        deprecated = false
        records = true
        immutablePojos = true
        fluentSetters = true
      }
      target {
        directory = "$projectDir/src/main/auto_generated"
        packageName = 'jooq'
      }
    }
  }
}

run.dependsOn startEmbeddedMysql

dependencies {
    runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"

    compile "org.pac4j:ratpack-pac4j:${ratpackPac4jVersion}"
    compile "io.ratpack:ratpack-groovy:${ratpackVersion}"
    compile "io.ratpack:ratpack-test:${ratpackVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-core:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-openid:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-http:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-gae:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-oidc:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-jwt:${pac4jVersion}"
    compile ratpack.dependency('hikari')
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13"
    compile group: 'io.ratpack', name: 'ratpack-thymeleaf', version: '1.4.0-rc-3'
    compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34"
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.2.Final'

}

mainClassName = "xyz.mealsahead.Main"
```

Running "gradle run" works fine, so I assume it's downloading that new version of jooq, but now I don't see any code generated.  I see the following message:

```
$ gradle generateSampleJooqSchemaSource 
:generateSampleJooqSchemaSource UP-TO-DATE
```

Can someone tell me if I:

- am using the appropriate gradle-jooq plugin for this?
- have misconfigured the new generator syntax from the previous version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Regarding your manual setup of the jOOQ code generator

Indeed, due to the upcoming modularisation of jOOQ 3.12, some split packages had to be renamed, namely the `org.jooq.util` package. In your manual setup, you need to change your imports from:

```
import org.jooq.util.jaxb.*
import org.jooq.util.*
```

To

```
import org.jooq.codegen.*
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*
import org.jooq.meta.*
```

#### Regarding your usage of the third party Gradle plugin

Do note that schema names are case sensitive, so probably it would help replacing this:

```
inputSchema = 'public'
```

By this

```
inputSchema = 'PUBLIC'
```

You already had it correct earlier: `.withInputSchema("PUBLIC")`

Comment: It was the casing!  Thank you so much.  I now need to read up on that function so I can understand it, but I appreciate the simple fix.  I actually copied that pasting from an example and noticed it, but figured it didn't matter since I pulled it from an example.

Comment: @voodoogiant: *"actually copied that pasting from an example and noticed it, but figured it didn't matter since I pulled it from an example"*, yeah, PostgreSQL report case insensitive names as lower case, other databases report them as upper case :-/